# Using a variable to represent arguments?

Tags: list

If I have a massive argument list like:

```
program :-
    function(bxcjhbxhcbdbhbxzhbfhxhfbghfghjdfhgxfh),
    another_function(bxcjhbxhcbdbhbxzhbfhxhfbghfghjdfhgxfh).
```

can i do something like:

```
program :-
    var = bxcjhbxhcbdbhbxzhbfhxhfbghfghjdfhgxfh
    function(var),
    another_function(var).
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you could do that in Prolog.

But you need to

- add a `,` at the end of the `var = ....` line).
- use Capital First Letters for variable names.

This works:

```
function([1, 2]).
another_function([1, 2]).

program :-
    Var = bxcjhbxhcbdbhbxzhbfhxhfbghfghjdfhgxfh,
    function(Var),
    another_function(Var).
```

Comment: its the exact syntax i used in my question??

Comment: Yes, but you need to add a `,` at the end of the `var = ...` line.

Comment: a typo: `Bxcjhbxhcbdbhbxzhbfhxhfbghfghjdfhgxfh` is a singleton variable now

Comment: @peroni_santo no, it is very important that Var starts with a capital (upper case) letter as any logical variable must. `Var = data` is not a declaration, it is a unification of logical variable named `Var`, and `data`. The comma `,` after it signifies an `AND`; you could also have `;` there, which stands for `OR`. Logvars exist in their own right, and can be uninstantiated as well as instantiated. Just by writing `X=1` we create a logvar `X` and unify it with ("instantiate it as") `1`. We could write `X=Y` which would create two uninstantiated logvars `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Is the use of `[1,2]` in the initial definitions of `function` and `another_function` significant or necessary? To me it looks like the functions are defined for lists, then you pass them the `Var` which is unified to the long, tedious-to-type atom.